# SQL Statement Dump Issue

Tags: sql, paradox

I'm trying to find out why some of my order numbers in my table are dumping out there appropriate data while others aren't.

Here I'm trying to dump out data from a specific order number and it won't dump its data for the `COMPLEX CITY`, `COMPLEX NAME` and `ORDERNUM`. However, when I just select the columns it dumps there data and shows the corresponding data relating to the ordernum.

I'm using ColdFusion. Here is my code.

```
<cfquery name="communities" datasource="pdoxtest">
 SELECT DISTINCT 
 [COMPLEX CITY] as COMPLEXCITY, 
 [COMPLEX NAME] as COMPLEXNAME,
 [COMPLEX ST] as COMPLEXST,
 [ORDERNUM]
 FROM SCHEDULE
 WHERE COMPLEXNAME = 'FORGE HOMESTEAD'
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#communities#">
```

When I dump out this data it appears like this:

[image]
However, when I try to dump out a query like this:

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="pdoxtest">
 SELECT DISTINCT 
 [COMPLEX CITY] as COMPLEXCITY, 
 [COMPLEX NAME] as COMPLEXNAME,
 [COMPLEX ST] as COMPLEXST,
 [ORDERNUM]
 FROM SCHEDULE
 WHERE ORDERNUM = '144873'
</cfquery>

<cfdump var="#test#">
```

Nothing gets returned: Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because when I enter a different ordernumber in the `WHERE` clause for a different `COMPELXNAME` data gets returned while some of the `ORDERNUM` doesn't like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is sample of "WHAT YOU SEE IS NOT WHAT YOU GET":

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
 [COMPLEX CITY] as COMPLEXCITY, 
 [COMPLEX NAME] as COMPLEXNAME,
 [COMPLEX ST] as COMPLEXST,
 [ORDERNUM]
 FROM SCHEDULE
 WHERE ORDERNUM LIKE '%144873%';
```

I suspect that `ORDERNUM` column is text and you probably have some whitespaces/control characters.

**EDIT:**

`%` is wildcard and it will match any characters. I propose to copy value to some text editor like Notepad++, enable show all characters and check for spaces/carriage return/tabs and so on.

You could think about cleansing data too.

Comment: It works! Thank you. Can you explain what %% means? thats a SQL wildcard right?

Comment: Okay thank you I'll look more into wildcards. Appreciate the help